# Can 2 blocks have the same previous hash?

Tags: blockchain

Can two blocks have the same **Previous** hash after being created.

2 blocks totally different from each other but with the same previous hash

Answer (score 3):

> Can two blocks have the same Previous hash after being created.

Yes, two otherwise valid blocks could be created that both link to the same parent block, but importantly: **only one of those two blocks will become a part of the valid chain**. So ultimately, only one of them will be valid, and the winner will be the block that miners build on top of first (and thus it becomes a part of the longer chain).

The other block will become what is called an ['orphan block'](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5859/what-are-orphaned-and-stale-blocks) (though some people prefer the more exact term, 'extinct block').

You can look through the [orhpaned-blocks](/questions/tagged/orhpaned-blocks) tag for more info.

Comment: What happens to the transactions on the orphan block?

Comment: @Juan simply: they are no longer a part of the blockchain record.

Comment: So that money is gone for good? The money X person sent to z person no longer exists?

Comment: @Juan no, the bitcoin would still exist, but the transaction sending it from X->Z would not (unless that transaction is also confirmed in the longest valid chain).

Comment: Oh okay, so you would have to send the transaction again so Z can get it

Comment: @Juan: In fact, other miners will normally consider transactions from the orphan block for inclusion in future blocks on the main chain.  So the sender typically doesn't have to do anything except wait a little longer for confirmation.